# Prediction interval for lmer() mixed effects model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, prediction-interval, lme4-nlme

I want to get a prediction interval around a prediction from a lmer() model. I have found some discussion about this:

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/24365_2803ab8299934e888a60e7b16113f619.html

http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq

but they seem to not take the uncertainty of the random effects into account.

Here's a specific example. I am racing gold fish. I have data on the past 100 races. I want to predict the 101st, taking into account uncertainty of my RE estimates, and FE estimates. I am including a random intercept for fish (there are 10 different fish), and fixed effect for weight (less heavy fish are quicker).

```
library("lme4")

fish <- as.factor(rep(letters[1:10], each=100))
race <- as.factor(rep(900:999, 10))
oz <- round(1 + rnorm(1000)/10, 3)
sec <- 9 + rep(1:10, rep(100,10))/10 + oz + rnorm(1000)/10

fishDat <- data.frame(fishID = fish, 
      raceID = race, fishWt = oz, time = sec)
head(fishDat)
plot(fishDat$fishID, fishDat$time)

lme1 <- lmer(time ~ fishWt + (1 | fishID), data=fishDat)
summary(lme1)
```

Now, to predict the 101st race. The fish have been weighed and are ready to go:

```
newDat <- data.frame(fishID = letters[1:10], 
    raceID = rep(1000, 10),
    fishWt = 1 + round(rnorm(10)/10, 3))
newDat$pred <- predict(lme1, newDat)
newDat

   fishID raceID fishWt     pred
1       a   1000  1.073 10.15348
2       b   1000  1.001 10.20107
3       c   1000  0.945 10.25978
4       d   1000  1.110 10.51753
5       e   1000  0.910 10.41511
6       f   1000  0.848 10.44547
7       g   1000  0.991 10.68678
8       h   1000  0.737 10.56929
9       i   1000  0.993 10.89564
10      j   1000  0.649 10.65480
```

Fish D has really let himself go (1.11 oz) and is actually predicted to lose to Fish E and Fish F, both of whom he has been better than in the past. However, now I want to be able to say, "Fish E (weighing 0.91oz) will beat Fish D (weighing 1.11oz) with probability p." Is there a way to make such a statement using lme4? I want my probability p to take into account my uncertainty in both the fixed effect, and the random effect.

Thanks!

PS looking at the `predict.merMod` documentation, it suggests "There is no option for computing standard errors of predictions because it is difficult to define an efficient method that incorporates uncertainty in the variance parameters; we recommend `bootMer` for this task," but by golly, I cannot see how to use `bootMer` to do this. It seems `bootMer` would be used to get bootstrapped confidence intervals for parameter estimates, but I could be wrong.

### **UPDATED Q:**

OK, I think I was asking the wrong question. I want to be able to say, "Fish A, weighing w oz, will have a race time that is (lcl, ucl) 90% of the time."

In the example I have laid out, Fish A, weighing 1.0 oz, will have a race time of `9 + 0.1 + 1 = 10.1 sec` on average, with a standard deviation of 0.1. Thus, his observed race time will be between

```
x <- rnorm(mean = 10.1, sd = 0.1, n=10000)
quantile(x, c(0.05,0.50,0.95))
       5%       50%       95% 
 9.938541 10.100032 10.261243
```

90% of the time. I want a prediction function that attempts to give me that answer. Setting all `fishWt = 1.0` in `newDat`, re-running the sim, and using (as suggested by Ben Bolker below)

```
predFun <- function(fit) {
  predict(fit,newDat)
}
bb <- bootMer(lme1,nsim=1000,FUN=predFun, use.u = FALSE)
predMat <- bb$t
```

gives

```
> quantile(predMat[,1], c(0.05,0.50,0.95))
      5%      50%      95% 
10.01362 10.55646 11.05462
```

This seems to actually be centered around the population average? As if it's not taking the FishID effect into account? I thought maybe it was a sample size issue, but when I bumped the number of observed races from 100 to 10000, I still get similar results.

I'll note `bootMer` uses `use.u=FALSE` by default. On the flip side, using

```
bb <- bootMer(lme1,nsim=1000,FUN=predFun, use.u = TRUE)
```

gives

```
> quantile(predMat[,1], c(0.05,0.50,0.95))
      5%      50%      95% 
10.09970 10.10128 10.10270
```

That interval is too narrow, and would seem to be a confidence interval for Fish A's mean time. I want a confidence interval for Fish A's observed race time, not his average race time. How can I get that?

### **UPDATE 2, ALMOST:**

I *thought* I found what I was looking for in [Gelman and Hill (2007)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) , page 273. Need to utilize the `arm` package.

```
library("arm")
```

For Fish A:

```
x.tilde <- 1    #observed fishWt for new race
sigma.y.hat <- sigma.hat(lme1)$sigma$data        #get uncertainty estimate of our model
coef.hat <- as.matrix(coef(lme1)$fishID)[1,]    #get intercept (random) and fishWt (fixed) parameter estimates
y.tilde <- rnorm(1000, coef.hat %*% c(1, x.tilde), sigma.y.hat) #simulate
quantile (y.tilde, c(.05, .5, .95))

  5%       50%       95% 
 9.930695 10.100209 10.263551
```

For all the fishes:

```
x.tilde <- rep(1,10)  #assume all fish weight 1 oz
#x.tilde <- 1 + rnorm(10)/10  #alternatively, draw random weights as in original example
sigma.y.hat <- sigma.hat(lme1)$sigma$data
coef.hat <- as.matrix(coef(lme1)$fishID)
y.tilde <- matrix(rnorm(1000, coef.hat %*% matrix(c(rep(1,10), x.tilde), nrow = 2 , byrow = TRUE), sigma.y.hat), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
quantile (y.tilde[,1], c(.05, .5, .95))
       5%       50%       95% 
 9.937138 10.102627 10.234616
```

Actually, this probably isn't exactly what I want. I'm only taking into account the overall model uncertainty. In a situation where I have, say, 5 observed races for Fish K and 1000 observed races for Fish L, I think the uncertainty associated with my prediction for Fish K should be much larger than the uncertainty associated with my prediction for Fish L.

Will look further into Gelman and Hill 2007. I feel I may end up having to switch to BUGS (or Stan).

### **UPDATE THE 3rd:**

Perhaps I am conceptualizing things poorly. Using the `predictInterval()` function given by Jared Knowles in an answer below gives intervals that aren't quite what I would expect...

```
library("lattice")
library("lme4")
library("ggplot2")

fish <- c(rep(letters[1:10], each = 100), rep("k", 995), rep("l", 5))
oz <- round(1 + rnorm(2000)/10, 3)
sec <- 9 + c(rep(1:10, each = 100)/10,rep(1.1, 995), rep(1.2, 5)) + oz + rnorm(2000)

fishDat <- data.frame(fishID = fish, fishWt = oz, time = sec)
dim(fishDat)
head(fishDat)
plot(fishDat$fishID, fishDat$time)

lme1 <- lmer(time ~ fishWt + (1 | fishID), data=fishDat)
summary(lme1)
dotplot(ranef(lme1, condVar = TRUE))
```

I have added two new fish. Fish K, for whom we have observed 995 races, and Fish L, for whom we have observed 5 races. We have observed 100 races for Fish A-J. I fit the same `lmer()` as before. Looking at the `dotplot()` from the `lattice` package:

[image: FishID Estimates]

By default, `dotplot()` reorders the random effects by their point estimate. The estimate for Fish L is on the top line, and has a very wide confidence interval. Fish K is on the third line, and has a very narrow confidence interval. This makes sense to me. We have lots of data on Fish K, but not a lot of data on Fish L, so we are more confident in our guesstimate about Fish K's true swimming speed. Now, I would think this would lead to a narrow prediction interval for Fish K, and a wide prediction interval for Fish L when using `predictInterval()`. Howeva:

```
newDat <- data.frame(fishID = letters[1:12],
                     fishWt = 1)

preds <- predictInterval(lme1, newdata = newDat, n.sims = 999)
preds
ggplot(aes(x=letters[1:12], y=fit, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), data=preds) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_linerange() +
  labs(x="Index", y="Prediction w/ 95% PI") + theme_bw()
```

[image: Prediction Interval for Fish]

All of those prediction intervals appear to be identical in width. Why isn't our prediction for Fish K narrower the others? Why isn't our prediction for Fish L wider than others?

Comment: `predictInterval` includes the error/uncertainty for both the fixed and random effect terms. In `dotplot` you are only seeing the uncertainty due to the random portion of the prediction, essentially the uncertainty around the estimate of the fish specific intercepts. If your model has a lot of uncertainty in the fixed parameter `fishWt` and this parameter drives most of the predicted value, then the uncertainty around any specific fish intercept is trivial and you won't see a big difference in the width of the intervals. We should make this more clear in `predictInterval` results.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This question and excellent exchange was the impetus for creating the `predictInterval` function in the `merTools` package. `bootMer` is the way to go, but for some problems it is not feasible computationally to generate bootstrapped refits of the whole model (in cases where the model is large).

In those cases, `predictInterval` is designed to use the `arm::sim` functions to generate distributions of parameters in the model and then to use those distributions to generate simulated values of the response given the `newdata` provided by the user. It's simple to use -- all you would need to do is:

```
library(merTools)
preds <- predictInterval(lme1, newdata = newDat, n.sims = 999)
```

You can specify a whole host of other values to `predictInterval` including setting the interval for the prediction intervals, choosing whether to report the mean or median of the distribution, and choosing whether or not to include the residual variance from the model.

It's not a full prediction interval because the variability of the `theta` parameters in the `lmer` object are not included, but all of the other variation is captured through this method, giving a pretty decent approximation.

Comment: This looks awesome! Reading through the [vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html) now. Thanks!

Comment: The prediction intervals aren't quite what I expected. See update 3 above.

Comment: Does `predictInterval()` not like nested random effects? For example, using the `msleep` dataset from the `ggplot2` package:
`mod <- lmer(sleep_total ~ bodywt + (1|vore/order),
     data=msleep);
predInt <- predictInterval(merMod=mod, newdata=msleep)`
 Returns an error: `Error in '[.data.frame'(newdata, , j) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: I bet that it does not like nested effects. I don't think we had any tests of it in our test suite. I'll file an issue on GitHub to look into that. I'd also recommend trying the dev version from GitHub `devtools::install_github("jknowles/merTools")` first.

Comment: As an update, the latest development version of merTools does allow nested effects. It will be pushed to CRAN shortly.

Comment: What about unconditional prediction intervals?  I have a model that I would like to generate prediction intervals on new data about which the random effects are unknown.  Say you had a new fish that was not part of the original trials, but you do know it's weight.  How could you generate a prediction interval with `predictInterval()`?

Comment: The only option I see in that case is to base the prediction interval on the fixed effect and model variability. Since you do not know what the group effect would be on the prediction, nor how precise it is, you could assign it to an unobserved factor level and `predictInterval` should just set the random effect to 0. If you wanted to do more than that, you could assign the same observation to various groups from the random effect distribution and simulate what the range of possible effects might be, and `merTools` contains examples of how to do this.

Comment: @jknowles Do I understand correctly from the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/merTools.pdf) that a prediction interval with uncertainty of random *and* fixed effects is now available through `which = "full"`?

Comment: Yes @FransRodenburg - `which="full"` implements the strategy described in my comment above.

Answer (score 21):

Do this by making `bootMer` generate a set of predictions for each parametric bootstrap replicate:

```
predFun <- function(fit) {
    predict(fit,newDat)
}
bb <- bootMer(lme1,nsim=200,FUN=predFun,seed=101)
```

The output of `bootMer` is in a not-terribly-transparent `"boot"` object, but we can get the raw predictions out of the `$t` component.

How much of the time does Fish E beat Fish D?

```
predMat <- bb$t
dim(predMat) ## 200 rows (PB reps) x 10 (predictions)
```

Fish E's times are in column 5, fish D's times are in column 4, so we just need to know the proportion that column 5 is less than column 4:

```
mean(predMat[,5]<predMat[,4])  ## 0.57
```

Comment: I'm getting some unexpected results. If I set fishWt = 1 for all fish in newDat, I would expect the mean/median time for Fish A to be ~ 10.1, Fish B ~ 10.2, ... , Fish J ~ 11.0 (since their time in the training data is defined as: `sec <- 9 + rep(1:10, rep(100,10))/10 + oz + rnorm(1000)/10`). When I use `predict()`, prediction times for Fish A, E, and J are 10.09, 10.49, and 10.99, as expected. However, median times for the bootMer method you descirbe are: 10.52, 10.59, and 10.50. I would have expected more agreement?

Comment: Using `use.u=TRUE` as in: `bb <- bootMer(lme1,nsim=200,FUN=predFun,seed=101,use.u=TRUE)` seems to give me what I want. Thanks!

Comment: OK, this gets a little tricky.  You need to look at the `use.u` argument to `bootMer`.  The question is, when you say "uncertainty in the fixed effect and the random effect", what do you mean by 'the random effect'?  Do you mean uncertainty in the random-effects *variance*, or in the *conditional modes* (i.e. the fish-specific effects)?  You can use `use.u=TRUE`, but I don't think it will necessarily do what you want ...

Comment: If I use `use.u=TRUE`, then the "values of u [stay] fixed at their estimated values". I interpret this as meaning, whatever our random effect point estimate for Fish A is, it is taken as The God's Honest Truth, if you will. `bootMer` assumes there is no error in our RE point estimate. If I use `use.u=FALSE`, does `bootMer` take into account the RE point estimates at all? It seems `bootMer` results when using `use.u=FALSE` are equivalent (or, asymptotically equiv) to using `re.form=NA` in the `predict()` statement. Is that true?

Comment: I think it's not implemented ATM, but you can extract the conditional variances of the conditional modes/BLUPs via `c(attr(ranef(lme1,condVar=TRUE)[[1]],"postVar"))` (they're all identical in this example), and then sample those values.